# What files and folders to copy when moving Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm kinda still finding my way around the Laravel development framework. I want to use a [Sample Project Here](https://startlaravel.com/themes/sb-admin-laravel-5/) for my learning

Now the project was done in Laravel 5 and i'm trying to use the Latest 5.5 Laravel.

How do i go about this and what files and folders do i have to copy to my Laravel 5.5 project to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file and code structure has changed quite a lot from Laravel 5.0 to Laravel 5.5.

If you are wanting to use that project on Laravel 5.5 then you would need to go through the update process for each version until you reached Laravel 5.5. These can all be found in the Laravel documentation for the respective version.

An easy, and better approach, would just be to incorporate this into your project manually.

SB Admin is just a theme based on Bootstrap and so you can just incorporate it into your app as you would Bootstrap.

You can download the source for SB Admin here - https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/

You can also check out the source on GitHub if you need more of an idea on how to use it on specific pages - https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-sb-admin

---

If you really want to use that project to learn Laravel then you can. As you're still new to Laravel, I wouldn't bother updating it (you'd likely be in over your head).

To get started with the project, just follow the instructions on their repo - https://github.com/start-laravel/sb-admin-laravel-5:

1. Clone the project `git clone https://github.com/start-laravel/sb-admin-laravel-5.git`
2. Switch into the newly created folder
3. `composer install` to install Laravel and the required dependencies
4. `npm install`
5. `bower install`

Comment: Thnx for the ideas shared. I think you're right, i will stick with the advice of keeping it simple for now and try to do the upgrade in a few months when my LaraSkills improve. Lol